# get the javascript array in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, arrays

here is my code:

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from views import show,showpage

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       (r'^$',showpage),
                       (r'^show/$',show),
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def show(request):
  arr = reqeust.GET.get('arr','Nothing')
  print arr#**it's 'Nothing'**
  if arr == 'Nothing':
    msg = 'fail'
  else:
    msg = 'pass'
  return HttpResponse(msg)

def showpage(request):
  html = '''    <html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="input_btn"/>
</body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#input_btn").bind("click",function(){
    arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"/show/",
      data:{arr:arr},//**I want pass the arr to django**
      success:function(data){alert(data);},
      error:function(data){alert(data);}
    });
  });
})
</script>
</html>'''
  return HttpResponse(html)
```

when I access **localhost:8000**,and click the button,I got 'Nothing' printed in the backend console,as you know I got message 'fail' in the frontend

uh..can anybody sovle this problem,I want get the code (`arr = reqeust.GET.get('arr','Nothing')`) which return a list(`[1,2,3,4,5,6]`) or something like this

---------append1-------

I got this in the console when I click the btn

**[12/Jun/2012 09:48:44] "GET /show/?arr%5B%5D=1&arr%5B%5D=2&arr%5B%5D=3&arr%5B%5D=4&arr%5B%5D=5&arr%5B%5D=6 HTTP/1.1" 200 4**

---------apend2-------

I fixed my code like this:

```
arr = request.GET.get('arr[]','Nothing')
```

and I got 6 which is the last one of the javascript array,how can I get the whole array?

thanks advance!

Comment: What does the actual request URL look like?

Comment: sorry! I forget return the html page,wait a minute

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I fixed my question and I put the request URL at the bottom of the question content

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery has decided to add square brackets to the field name, most likely to accommodate PHP. They aren't required for Django, but whatever. Access `request.GET['arr[]']` and `request.GET.getlist('arr[]')` instead.

Comment: **request.GET.getlist('arr[]')** works!! and I serached info about the request url **arr%5B%5D=1&arr%5B%5D=2** EQUALS **arr[]=1&arr[]=2**.and the **request.GET** returns **QueryDict** thank you @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams ^_^

Answer (score 5):

You can also set:

```
$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

This will make jQuery behave according to the actual HTTP standard, which works with Django.

This is required when you're not going to access request.GET or request.POST yourself (ie. ajax-posting a form).

It's definitively recommended to set this in *every* django project.

Comment: thank you @jpic all the same,I try your suggestion and I get the request url like this:**http://127.0.0.1:8000/show/?arr=1&arr=2&arr=3&arr=4&arr=5&arr=6**.I change **request.GET.getlist('arr')**,I works too.thanks your suggeistion~